# GCM example that isn't deprecated?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a GCM example all setup and it works fine but it seems to be deprecated. I have attempted to look for any decent example that is not deprecated so that I can at least translate my old code to the new GCM version. The problem is that for the Google example that they give [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) they only show some of the basic things, with large parts missing that were once required. The issue furthers when I see them reference .MyIntentService which they do not give any reference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient2) has been updated to the new `GoogleCloudMessaging` APIs. In includes a few classes that are workalikes to the old API, to try to reduce the number of changes needed to move from the old API to the one.

Note that the old API still works, AFAIK.

Also, FWIW, [here's the original version](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Push/GCMClient) of the same sample, using the original API.

Comment: Wow! Now that is awesome, Thank you I wish I could give you a few thousand +1s for that answer as there are other examples that you have made that will help me with other things. Thanks for the quick and great answer!

Comment: @Kebob: I ran into the same frustrations as you when I was updating my GCM chapter in [my book](http://commonsware.com/Android), as not only did the GCM docs get worse IMHO, but they deprecated stuff that we still need. That's why I cross-ported some of the old `gcm.jar` code and put it in this sample. Now, that cross-port isn't complete, as I focused mostly on the bits that I needed for the chapter, but you could grab other stuff as well. The old source should still be in your SDK installation.

Comment: Yes I saw that, Thanks for that help. If I cross port more would you like me to let you know and send you the code? I will be at this for awhile as I am making a turn based game between devices.

Comment: @Kebob: "If I cross port more would you like me to let you know and send you the code?" -- no, as I don't really need it personally. You might consider putting it up on a repository somewhere, though. "I will be at this for awhile as I am making a turn based game between devices" -- that's certainly far more practical nowadays with upstream messaging.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Both pages are not found, Source links are broken, would you please update it ?

Comment: @Er.KaushikKajavadara: I am no longer supporting those projects. This answer is over three years old, and nothing in those projects would work with modern FCM. I would delete the answer, but I cannot delete accepted answers.