# Google Cloud Messaging - Check if device is already registered

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I just set up GCM in my Android App. But I have the problem that I don't know how to check if the device is already registered. I work with the new google play services library.

The register part looks like this:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context_app);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Dvice registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                Log.d("111", msg);
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend(regid);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            }
            return msg;
        }
```

How can I modify this that it checks if the device is already registered?

Comment: store it and check through `SharedPreference`s, when user uninstalls the app and reinstalls basically reset all preferences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Corresponding GCMRegistrar.isRegistered() in new GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492268/corresponding-gcmregistrar-isregistered-in-new-gcm)

Comment: `GCMRegister` is obsolete now. You should be using `GoogleCloudMessaging` from Google Play Services.

Comment: doesn't google refresh its tokens every 6 months. if you just store it in a file in the app then when it gets refreshed you will still be sending the same bad token to the app server and it will fail every time no?

Answer (score 0):

Store the registration id in a databade table or shared preference and when app starting..check whether it is null or not

Comment: Same. is there any way to know if user uninstalled the app ?

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided very clear documentation with code.You should use following code:

```
// Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
 // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
        // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
 registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Automatically registers application on startup.
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            // Device is already registered on GCM, check server.
            if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                // Skips registration.
                mDisplay.append(getString(R.string.already_registered) + "\n");
            } else {
                // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                final Context context = this;
                mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        boolean registered =
                                ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                        // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                        // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                        // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                        // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                        // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                        // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                        if (!registered) {
                            GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        mRegisterTask = null;
                    }

                };
                mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
            }
        }
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
  private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
            new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            mDisplay.append(newMessage + "\n");
        }
    };
```

Comment: but GCMRegistrar doesn't work with the new google play services lib

Comment: why cant it find GCMRegistrar then? I have added the google play services lib in my project already

Comment: post log so I can find exact solution

Comment: I just mentioned that when I'm add gcm.jar to the lib folder its working. But I thought gcm.jar is deprecated, am I right?

Comment: And how do I use it? I already added the play services lib to my project but then the above code isn't working

Comment: @Phil it has been deprecated but it still working u can use this sample code provided by Google or look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090723/gcm-example-that-isnt-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

when you get registration Id, Store it in SharedPreferences, for example:

```
SharedPreferences shp = context.getSharedPreferences("anyNameYouLike",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=shp.edit();
editor.putString("RegID",registrationID).commit;
```

In the next time before you register check the "anyNameYouLike" if it contain field called RegID Like this:

```
private boolean isRegistered(Context context){
SharedPreferences shp = context.getSharedPreferences("anyNameYouLike",PRIVATE_MODE);
return shp.contains("RegID");
}
```